# How does shared_ptr work in if condition

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

In C++, I can write something like:

```
shared_ptr<A> a_sp = someFunctionReturningSharedPtr();
if (a_sp) {
    cout << a_sp->someData << endl;
} else {
    cout << "Shared Pointer is NULL << endl;
}
```

Why does `if (a_sp)` check work correctly? `a_sp` is not a boolean, but how is it checked for true or false? How does the if condition know to check the result of `a_sp.get()` function? Or if it does not, how is the `NULL`ity of the `a_sp` checked? Is there some function in `shared_ptr` defined that converts it to boolean value?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`shared_ptr` has an `operator unspecified-bool-type() const` that allows it to be used in boolean contexts. The *unspecified-bool-type* is typically defined as a pointer to function, or pointer to member-function, to disallow accidental matching to bool function overloads.

In `C++0x` the idiom is to use `explicit operator bool() const;`, which disallows implicit conversions (such as function calls, conversions to `int` for arithmetic, and so on), but still allows the `shared_ptr` to be converted to bool in boolean contexts.

Comment: Mankarse: What is this syntax `operator unspecified-bool-type()`. I haven't seen this before. Is this something special to boost?

Comment: unspecified-bool-type is just a stand in for an actual type, such as bool. This syntax is not a special boost thing, it is the syntax for declaring a "type conversion operator". See [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Operators/Operator_Overloading#Conversion_operators)

Comment: Mankarse: Awesome. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

shared_ptr has operator bool(), which returns true if it is not empty.

For example, this is Microsoft implementation of shared_ptr::operator bool(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982901.aspx

shared_ptr::operator boolean-type - Tests if an owned resource exists.

Comment: That is only conceptually correct, but not actually: http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html; but it's to be fixed with explicit conversion operators: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2435.htm