# Using Point Cloud Library to store Point Clouds from Kinect

Tags: kinect, openni, point-clouds, point-cloud-library

Using Point Cloud Library on Ubuntu, I am trying to take multiple point clouds from the Kinect and store them in memory for later use in the program. My code shown at the bottom of this post is designed to store the first Point Cloud from the Kinect and output its width and height. The program gives me a runtime error:

```
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:418: T* boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
```

**All help is greatly appreciated and I always accept an answer!**

The code:

```
  #include <pcl/io/openni_grabber.h>
  #include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>

 class SimpleOpenNIViewer
 {
  public:
  SimpleOpenNIViewer () : viewer ("PCL OpenNI Viewer") {}

 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr prevCloud;


  void cloud_cb_ (const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr &cloud)
  {


if (!viewer.wasStopped())
   viewer.showCloud (cloud);


//ICP start
if(!prevCloud) {
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr prevCloud( new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>());

    pcl::copyPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ>(*cloud, *prevCloud);
}

cout << prevCloud->width << " by " << prevCloud->height << endl; 



  }

  void run ()
  {
    pcl::Grabber* interface = new pcl::OpenNIGrabber();

    boost::function<void (const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr&)> f =
      boost::bind (&SimpleOpenNIViewer::cloud_cb_, this, _1);


    interface->registerCallback (f);

    interface->start ();


    while (!viewer.wasStopped())
    {
      boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::seconds (1));
    }

    interface->stop ();
  }

  pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer;
 };

  int main ()
{
 SimpleOpenNIViewer v;
 v.run ();
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I don't have the Kinect drivers installed so I can't test. Basically in my version prevCloud is instantiated in the constructor so `(!prevCloud)` will always equal 'false'. Which is to say `prevCloud.get() != NULL`.

```
#include <pcl/io/openni_grabber.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>

class SimpleOpenNIViewer
{
typedef pcl::PointXYZ                           Point;
typedef pcl::PointCloud<Point>                  PointCloud;
public:
SimpleOpenNIViewer () : viewer ("PCL OpenNI Viewer") {
        prevCloud = PointCloud::Ptr(NULL);
    }

void cloud_cb_ (const PointCloud::ConstPtr &cloud)
{
    if (!viewer.wasStopped())
        viewer.showCloud (cloud);
            if (!prevCloud) // init previous cloud if first frame
                    prevCloud = PointCloud::Ptr(new PointCloud);
            else.   // else RunICP between cloud and prevCloud
                    //RunICP(cloud,prevCloud);

            //Copy new frame in to prevCloud
    pcl::copyPointCloud<Point, Point>(*cloud, *prevCloud);
    cout << prevCloud->width << " by " << prevCloud->height << endl; 
}

void run ()
{
    pcl::Grabber* interface = new pcl::OpenNIGrabber();

    boost::function<void (const PointCloud::ConstPtr&)> f =
    boost::bind (&SimpleOpenNIViewer::cloud_cb_, this, _1);

    interface->registerCallback (f);
    interface->start ();


    while (!viewer.wasStopped())
    {
        boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::seconds (1));
    }

    interface->stop ();
}

PointCloud::Ptr prevCloud;
pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer;
};

int main ()
{
SimpleOpenNIViewer v;
v.run ();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get a series of 640x480's, so this seems to do what its supposed to do. However, I tried encasing the copyPointCloud statement in an if(!prevCloud) block, but then I got a series of 0x0's. Any idea why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226801/how-does-shared-ptr-work-in-if-condition  might help.  Basically in my version prevCloud is instantiated in the constructor so (!prevCloud) will always equal 'false'.  Which is to say prevCloud.get() != NULL.

Comment: I've come up with a temporary solution: if(prevCloud->width == 0), but this is obviously more like a workaround. Do you know of a more concrete solution?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the if statement?  If the program already copies the point cloud like it is supposed to are you trying to stop it from copying more than once?  Or do you want it to create a new cloud every single frame?

Comment: I am trying to use ICP to combine a bunch of the frames returned by the kinect. To do so, I need to save a cloud from every single frame.

Comment: Updated post, see if that's what you're looking for. As an aside, even basic ICP is going to cause significant slow down. You're better off saving each frame and post processing.

Comment: It worked but there was one thing I had to change: `prevCloud = PointCloud::Ptr(NULL);` causes a ton of errors. I replaced it with `prevCloud = PointCloud::Ptr();`. I have already edited your post to account for this change.

Comment: Do you use the boost library?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new local variable `prevCloud` and copying `cloud` into it, rather than copying into the `prevCloud` field. So, if the field's value was null before the `if {}`, it is still null after the `if {}` and so it throws an error when you try to dereference it.

Comment: Could you explain this further? I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: Before 'cloud_cb_' you define 'prevCloud', you then define it a second time inside of 'cloud_cb_'.

Comment: oh, I understand. But if I delete the definition inside cloud_cb_, I still get the same assertion error. How can I make the prevCloud variables global and avoid the double definition?

Comment: Change 'if(prevCloud == NULL)' to 'if(!prevCloud)' and make sure your code actually goes in to your if statement.  One additional comment, the way your code is written prevCloud will only ever be the first cloud read.  Unless somewhere else in the code you to delete prevCloud.

Comment: I have posted the updated code. I tried it, but I still got the same error (I made sure the code in the if statement was executed).

Answer (score 0):

May be this code can help you, the cloud is saved in a "pcd" file, take a look [here](https://github.com/jvcleave/PCL_1-3-0_Libraries_for_OF/blob/master/openni_grab_frame.cpp)

And other option is work with the "Kinfu" project from PCL